# C++ Error: Undefined Reference When Initializing a Class Object

Tags: c++, class, oop, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

This is my first step into the world of C++.  I am experimenting with a simple program that is using a class.  The program is to prompt the user for a username and age, then create a class object with the given data and then return the greet method which takes in the class object of Person and returns a greeting.  However, when I try to build to program I get the following error:

> "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" -g "D:\OOP Labs and Assignments\Lab5\lab5.cpp" -o "D:\OOP Labs and Assignments\Lab5\lab5.exe"
> C:\Users\okii_\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1mDRfr.o: In function `main': D:/OOP Labs and Assignments/Lab5/lab5.cpp:21: undefined reference to` Person::Person(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, int)'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

> Build finished with error(s).
> The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

I traced this back to where the error occurs and it seems to be happening when I try to create an object.  I am at a loss as to why I am getting this error.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I am using Visual Studio Code and g++ to compile my code and my files are below.

Person.hpp:

```
#ifndef PERSON_HPP
#define PERSON_HPP
#include <string>

class Person 
{
    private:
        // private section: private class members will be added here
        std::string name;
        int age;
    
    public:
        //pulic section: public class memeber will be added here
        // Constructor
        // Parameter theName: the name of the person
        // theAge: the age of the person
        Person(const std::string & theName, int theAge);

        // Get the name of the person, returned as a constant reference.
        const std::string & getName() const;

        // Get the age of the person
        int getAge() const;

        // Set age of the person
        void setAge(int value)
        {
            this->age = value;        
        }
};

#endif
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include "Person.hpp"
using namespace std;

Person::Person(const string & theName, int theAge)
    : name{theName}, age{theAge}
{} // empty body constructor

const string & Person::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

int Person::getAge() const
{
    return age;
}
```

lab5.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.hpp"
using namespace std;

void greet(const Person & p);

int main()
{
   string userName;
   int userAge;

   cout << "Enter your name: ";
   cin >> userName;
   cout << "Enter your age: ";
   cin >> userAge;

   Person thePerson(userName, userAge);
   greet(thePerson);
}

void greet(const Person & p)
{
   string name = p.getName();
   int age = p.getAge();

   cout << "Hello " << name;
   cout << "Your age is " << age;
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your "Undefined" symbol `Person::Person(const string &, int)` is defined in the file Person.cpp.  That file certainly exists somewhere on your computer, but it is not being compiled and linked as part of your project.

Comment: You're trying to build `lab5.cpp` directly into `lab5.exe`, without compiling `Person.cpp` at all. Typically C++ compilation has two stages: the first would be building the object files `lab5.o` (or `.obj` or whatever) and `Person.o`. The second stage, which you're jumping straight to, links those files into an executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Drew and Useless, I needed to compile my program first to resolve the error.  I compiled the program and it ran smoothly.